# How to Add a constraint based on another variable on LP using R?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-programming

I'm doing a script to identify the Best Budget Allocation using R on a Linear Program. I have a example that use only the ROI, but I want to add more constraints like "The minimal Conversion Rate" or any other metrics.

Follow the example

```
library (lpSolve)
library (linprog)

## Channel        ROI
## TV              8%
## Google Shop    12%
## Twitter         7%
## Facebook       11%
## Google Brand    4%

ROI <- c(0.08, 0.12, 0.07, 0.11, 0.4)

#b vector is the limits
b <- c(100, 0,0,0,10, 2700)

#a is the constraints

A <- rbind (
c(1,1,1,1,1), #first constraint total budget
c(0.42,-0.58,-0.58,-0.58,-0.58), #second constraint, TV can't be more than 58% of Budget
c(0.2,0.2,-0.8,-0.8,-0.8), #third constriant
c(-0.3, 0.7, 0.7, -0.3, 0.7), #forth constriant
c(0,0,0,1,0), #fifth constriant
)
solveLP(ROI, b, A, TRUE)
```

So basically, I have limits (constraints) for ROI, but it's possible to add constrains for another metric?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you give us more details about the constraint you want to add? (i.e. the formula)

Comment: The best approach is to first write down a mathematical model and then transcribe that into R code.